# What is the relation between the two definitions of typical set

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics, information-theory

In the 3rd chapter of the book *Elements of Information Theory*, typical set is defined as follows.
$$A_{\epsilon}^{n}=\{x^n: H(X)-\epsilon \le\frac{1}{n}\log p(x^n) \le H(X)+\epsilon\}$$
In the 11th chapter, another definition is given as:
$$T_{Q}^{\epsilon}=\{ x^n:D(P_{x^n})||Q)\le\epsilon\} $$
What is the relation between them? Which is stricter?